# JSHint: Asynchronous function in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jshint

I placed an asynchronous callback function (something like `$.ajax`) inside a `for` loop. It looked more or less like (edit: updated code, see comments):

```
var i = 0;

for ( ; i < 5; i++ ) {
  (function( index ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "",
      success: function() {
        console.log( index );
      }
    });
  })( i );
}
```

It worked, but JSHint gave me a warning saying something like:

> "Don't place functions inside loops"

Normally I could just place my `callback` function outside my loop and call that function for every iteration. Unfortunately I need access to variables, which are assigned inside the loop (e.g. `i`). So I'm looking for a solution to do something like below:

```
var i = 0;

function callback( data ) {
  // I want to have access to "i" (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and the AJAX "data"
  // in this function. But I only have access to "data", because "i"
  // will always be 5
}

for ( ; i < 5; i++ ) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    success: callback
  });
}
```

Comment: Well, in your first example, `i` will also be `5` in all callbacks. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196).

Comment: Do you have to loop...can't you send one request with all the data?

Comment: Just fix your for loop and add this line to your ajax call `async : false`

Comment: @RobertRozas uhm... please don't do that.

Comment: @KevinB, i missunderstood the problem, sorry :)

Comment: I mean, it would solve the problem, but... it's definitely not a very good way of doing things. It will result in the clients browser being locked up for a period of time.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, you are right. Actually I just took $.ajax as an example. In my case I need to loop over some addresses and geocode (async callback as well) them with Google Maps API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use a function that returns a function that has access to the data you need.

```
var i = 0;
function callback( i ) {
  return function (data) {
    // I want to have access to "i" (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and the AJAX "data"
    // in this function.
    console.log(i)
  }
}

for ( ; i < 5; i++ ) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    success: callback(i)
  });
}
```

however, it would of course be better to submit this data with a single request rather than looping.